# PowerShell replace string from Csv file

Tags: regex, powershell

Csv file contents some thousands of rows and want to replace text within it.

`MacBookPro*,*,` with `MacBookPro1*.*,`

'*' is wildcard here. 
Text looks something like this

```
MacBookPro13,1,
```

This to be replaced with

```
MacBookPro,
```

I am not good at regex and need help.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do that in Powershell and can check in the CSV as well.

```
$string_var = 'MacBookPro*,*,'
$newstring_var=$string_var.Replace($string_var,'MacBookPro1*.*,')
$newstring_var
```

Let me know if you mean this.

Comment: I am referring * as wildcard here. Sorry I was not clear. I am not able to figure out the regex to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Able to resolve it ...

```
(Get-Content $ExportCsvFilePath) -replace 'MacBookPro(.*?),(.*?),','MacBookPro,' | Set-Content -Path $ExportCsvFilePath -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple entries in the csv file this should replace all of them.

```
 $oldString = 'MacBookPro*,*,'
    $newString = 'MacBookPro1*.*,'
    $originalFilePath = "EnterPathToFileHere"
    $newFilePath = "EnterNewPathToFileHere"

    [io.file]::readalltext($originalFilePath).Replace($oldString, $newString) | Out-File $newFilePath -Encoding ascii –Force
```